# Jquery keypress ignore

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some Javascript to let the Spacebar pause the playing song. But the "event.stopInmediatePropagation(); doesn't seem to work....
I want to use this function to ignore the keyboard actions when in a form or something....
I'm using Bootstrap...

This is my code:

```
$('form').keypress(function(event){
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == '32'){
    }
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  });
$(document).keypress(function(event){
  var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
  if(keycode == '32'){
    if($('#play').is(":visible")){
      playNextSong(0);
    }
    else{
      pause();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Does switching around these two functions work (I'm thinking along the lines of 'the propagation continues on elements that have been tied to other elements _after_ the propagation prevention was declared'... ) I haven't tested as reproducing a setup would take a bit too much time. I'm also thinking that your 'form' does not necessarily take keypresses. You could always try to set a global var to true or false if your are in a form, and then propagate according to that.

Comment: First "doesn't seem to work" doesn't help us very much. Second, using `stopImmediatePropagation()` stops "bubbling up" the DOM. So it will never fire your document's keypress event. It also seems as though you have an empty if statement in your form keypress function...

Comment: .preventDefault()? Anyway you can check if the user is focusing the form instead. document is quite generic, for such an use.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using visibility to hide the play button you need to check if the element is visible with `$('#play').css("visibility") == "visible"`

```js
$('form').keypress(function(event) {
  var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
  if (keycode == '32') {}
  event.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).keypress(function(event) {
  var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
  if (keycode == '32') {
    if ($('#play').css("visibility") == "visible") {
      //playNextSong(0);
      $('#play').css("visibility", "hidden");      
    } else {
      //pause();
      $('#play').css("visibility", "visible");      
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="play">Play</div>

<form action="">
  <input type="text" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what's wrong with your code but your code is working in my demo below.

```js
$('form').keypress(function (event) {
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if (keycode == '32') {
      $("#output").append("space pressed in form<br/>");
    }
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
$(document).keypress(function (event) {

    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if (keycode == '32') {
        console.log("pressed space");
        $("#output").append("space pressed outside of form.<br/>");
        if ($('#play').is(":visible")) {
            playNextSong(0);
        } else {
            //console.log('pause');
            //pause();
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="text" />
</form>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: How does your html markup look like? Maybe there is something wrong,  e.g. if your input is without the form tag, it won't work.